# Why can't I destruct or discriminate here?

Tags: coq

I am proving the following theorem.

```
Definition excluded_middle := forall P : Prop,
  P \/ ~ P.

Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle ->
  forall (X:Type) (P : X -> Prop),
    ~ (exists x, ~ P x) -> (forall x, P x).
Proof.
  intros.
  unfold excluded_middle in H.
  unfold not in H0.
  unfold not in H.
  assert (P x \/ ~ P x).
  apply H.
  destruct H1.
  - apply H1.
  - unfold not in H1.
```

Currently, the goal is

```
1 goal
H : forall P : Prop, P \/ (P -> False)
X : Type
P : X -> Prop
H0 : (exists x : X, P x -> False) -> False
x : X
H1 : P x -> False
______________________________________(1/1)
P x
```

If I have a goal like `H -> False`, I have something that has `False` in my hypothesis, I  tend to use discriminate or destruct.
However, now I have `H -> False` in my hypothesis, and `H` in my goal. I wonder why I can't use discriminate or destruct any more?

BTW, I know I can use exfalso in this case. However, IMO exfalso also intros the H, and then destruct H. So Is there any way to do this with destruct or destruct, and without assert.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with `exfalso`. It is the right way to go here.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Yes. My question is exfalso is built from destruct. So if there any way to use only destruct to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`destruct H0` does the same as `exfalso; apply H0` (in a more primitive way).